# Weird performance of queries using 'max'

Tags: sql-server

We recently encountered a weird performance issue with SQL Server 2008

Given these two queries (which are equivalent)

```
select max(tfiv_value) from tablefieldintvalue where tfiv_fk_tablefield = 48
```

and

```
select max(tfiv_value) from tablefieldintvalue where tfiv_fk_tablefield = 
(select tbfl_pk from tablefield where tbfl_name = 'Field with pk 48')
```

The first one takes about 20 seconds, while the second one takes 0.

To be clear the subquery

```
(select tbfl_pk from tablefield where tbfl_name = 'Field with pk 48')
```

Has as its outcome 48.

We see in the query plan that it transforms the second query into a join, but this still does not explain to me why this performance difference happens. In my mind, if there would be a difference than the first one should be faster.

We have an index on all the relevant fields.

Comment: Are these timings consistent?  Or, did you just run the first one, note that it took a long time, and then run the second one?

Comment: They are consistent, the first query starts running a bit faster after a while (goes down to 6 seconds) but is still a lot slower then the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought, however, is that the first query filled the page cache and the second simply took advantage of it.  Caching can make a big difference.

If the timings are so different (and consistently so) for the two queries, then I would imagine that the difference is due to a table scan versus index use.  You can check this out by looking at the query plans.  The next question is:  "what would cause this?"

The first query would normally do an index scan . . . unless there are lots and lots of rows where `tfiv_fk_tablefield = 48`.  If it thought so, then it might do a table scan instead of an index scan.  That is, SQL Server has a "smart" optimizer that takes statistics into account.  And, it might choose the wrong approach when the statistics are out-of-date.

The second might force an index scan, because it is using a type of join.  In that case, out-of-date statistics would not have an effect, and the query does the right thing.

This is all speculation, of course.  You should look at the query plans and, if still appropriate include them in this or another question.

Comment: I think the statistics were really weird, after dropping indices it even started going faster. Now with good indices both queries run instantly. Can't really say I understand why, but thanks anyway!